# react-scripts-ts looks for dependencies in all folders and throws error on build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, single-page-application, react-fullstack

I build fullstack application using Node.js + Typescript and  React+ Typescript. 
Folder structure:

```
App
   -node_modules             //server part's dependencies
   -build                    //includes compiled server code
   -src
       -server
       -client
              -node_modules  //client part's dependencies
              tsconfig.json  //created by 'create-react-app'
              package.json   //created by 'create-react-app'
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
package.json                 // includes config for server compiling and running
```

So, when I execute command `tsc && node build/www` server starts.

But if I want to build react bundle with command `react-scripts-ts start`, I get errors that do not belong to the react project. For example:

```
Failed to compile.
~/projects/App/node_modules/@types/graphql/execution/execute.d.ts
(1,44): Cannot find module '../error'.
```

**Why does  react-scripts-ts look for dependencies in non-react folder?**

Answer (score 0):

Just add to client/tsconfig.json to compilerOptions next rule:
`"skipLibCheck": true`